# Is it possible to specialize an alias declaration?

Tags: c++

I can do this by using helper structs having a type member, but I was wondering whether it's possible with `using`. The below doesn't compile. Any workarounds besides using helper structs?

```
template<int ...>
struct A
{
};

template<typename>
using B;

template<int n, int ...ns>
using B<A<n, ns...>> = A<ns...>;
```

Comment: @KerrekSB One big benefit of the alias declarations is that they make code cleaner for example from `A<B>::Type` to `A<B>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I just answered myself ;)

Comment: @TartanLlama: Yeah, true. Never mind. I shouldn't post before coffee!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

```
template<int ...>
struct A;

template<typename>
struct B_;

template<int n, int ...ns>
struct B_<A<n, ns...>>
{
  typedef A<ns...> Type;
};

template<typename T>
using B = typename B_<T>::Type;
```

Comment: Isn't this precisely the "workaround with helper structs" you alluded to in the question?